# Download brochure depends on the hidden field value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an html website and using brochure download option with form. I have many forms for every project. I need only one form that downloads the brochure depends on the hidden input value of the project.

```
  jQuery(".form-js-pop-vedam").submit(function () {
  var thisform = jQuery(this);
  jQuery('.required-error',thisform).remove();
  
  var pmail = jQuery("#pmail").val();
  var pphone = jQuery("#pphone").val();
  var psubject = jQuery("#psubject").val();
  
  var data = {'pmail':pmail,'pphone':pphone,'psubject':psubject}
  
   if (pmail == "") {
    jQuery("#pmail").after('<span class="form-description  required-error">Required field.</span>');
  }else {
   jQuery("#pmail").parent().find('.required-error').remove();
  }
  if (pphone == "") {
   jQuery("#pphone").after('<span class="form-description   required-error">Required field.</span>');
  }else {
   jQuery("#pphone").parent().find('.required-error').remove();
  }
  
  if ( pmail != "" && pphone != "" ) {
   jQuery.post("contact_us_pop-vedam.php",data,function (result) {
    if (result == "done") {
     
    thisform.prepend("<div class='alert-message success-amairo'><i      class='icon-ok'></i><p><span>Vedam brochure was sent to your mail. Thank    you!</span></p></div>");
     jQuery("#pmail").val("");
     jQuery("#pphone").val("");
     
    }
   });
   }
  return false;
  });
 
 
    <form class="form-style form-js-pop-vedam" action="contact_us_pop-vedam.php" method=post>
  <input type="hidden" name="psubject" id="psubject" value="Brochure   Download from Vedam Page">

  <div class="col-md-6" ><input type=email class=required-item id=pmail name=pmail value="" aria-required=true placeholder="Your Email*"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6 " ><input class=required-item aria-required=true id=pphone name=pphone value="" placeholder="Your Phone*"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6 " ><input name=submit type=submit value="Download Now >" class="submit_buttom buttonColor-side" id="Brochure_Download"></div>
  </form>

 



<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php
function clean_text($text='') {
$text = trim($text);
$text = strip_tags($text);
$text = addslashes($text);
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
return $text;
}
if (!$_POST) {
die();
}else {
if (empty($_POST["pphone"]) && empty($_POST["pmail"]) ) {
    echo "all_empty";
}else if (empty($_POST["pmail"])) {
    echo "empty_mail";
}else if (empty($_POST["pphone"])) {
    echo "empty_phone";
}else {
    // edit this only :)
    $your_email = "me@myweb.com";



    $pmail   = clean_text($_POST["pmail"]);
    $pphone  = clean_text($_POST["pphone"]);
    $psubject    = clean_text($_POST["psubject"]);
    $subject  = "$psubject"; 



    $headers  = "From: leads@website.in" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'. "\r\n";
    $msg      = "New Brochure Download \n<br />";
    $msg     .= "Email : \t $pmail \r\n<br />";     
    $msg    .= "Phone : \t $pphone \r\n<br />";     


    echo "done";
    $done = @mail($your_email, $subject, $msg, $headers);
 }if($done)
   {

    if(($pmail)) {
        $headerRep  = "From: Website <info@website.in>";
        $subjectRep =   "Greetings from website!";
        $messageRep =   "Hi, \n\r
        Thanks for showing interest in our property \n\r";
        $messageRep .="You can download the brochure here  http://www.example.in/pdf/brochure.pdf";



        @mail($pmail, $subjectRep, $messageRep, $headerRep);
     }




   }



  }
   ?>
 <!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Thanks. This PHP and html i attached for only one project. I have many projects inside my website like this and for each project i have separate PHP files. Each project has separate brochure to download after filling the form. In PHP you can see the auto respond mail i attached in the bottom of the script.So Via hidden variable in the form I want to send the particular brochure. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets talk generally about word (hidden) .. We have 2 cases

**1st case:** the input with `type="hidden"` you can use a selector like this

in css

```
input[type="hidden"]{}
```

and in js

```
$('input[type="hidden"]') // you can use .val()  or .attr() depending on data you want from it
```

to check if the form has input with type hidden

```
if($('form').find('input[type="hidden"]').length > 0){ // in submit event use $(this).find   instead if $('form').find
   // yes this is input with type hidden here
}else{
   // no input with type hidden here
}
```

and while you said *(depends on the hidden input value)* you can check that with

```
if($('form').find('input[type="hidden"]').val() == 'something'){ // in submit event use $(this).find   instead if $('form').find
       // type input hidden value = something
    }else{
       // type input hidden value not = something
    }
```

**2nd case:** :hidden and :visible   and that's about element is visible or not  which I don't think you will need it here

Comment: Thanks. This PHP and html i attached for only one project. I have many projects inside my website like this and for each project i have separate PHP files. Each project has separate brochure to download after filling the form. In PHP you can see the auto respond mail i attached in the bottom of the script.So Via hidden variable in the form I want to send the particular brochure. Please help me!